# Unable to sign in to Azure AD from Angular app from Non-base URL

Tags: azure-active-directory

Recently, I configured a new Azure AD App Registration. It has a base URL of an Angular SPA registered as Reply URL. It all works fine when the user hits the website on base URL (ie, www.mysite.net) where the request is redirected to the Microsoft page where user signs-in and then is redirected back to the website.

However, when the user hits first a non-base URL (ie, www.mysite.net/admin/staff) then after sign in there is an error message displayed on https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/login

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'My-App-Id'.

As a walkaround, I could specify that URL (www.mysite.net/admin/staff) in the list of Reply URLs. But before, I always specified base urls as reply URLs. What am I doing wrong now?[image]

Comment: Back-end libraries usually use the base URL as the `redirect_uri`, and store the local URL in the `state`. In this case one option might be to tell ADAL.JS that you want to use the base URL always as the redirect URI. Then you could use session/local storage to store the local URL so you can then put them to the right place after authentication.

Comment: Putting all the URLs in the reply URLs is not feasible, so don't try that :)

Comment: Can you share the library (and version) you're using?

Comment: It's using ngx-adal ver 0.3.0. I suspect that it could be one of the culprits. However, we have another app developed a year ago and it works fine there.

Comment: Facing the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589254/azure-ad-returns-authenticated-as-false-when-trying-to-access-angular-7-child-ro Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding wildcard URLs for your reply URL(s)? If you add "/*" to your base URL then all other URL extensions should be able to work.

Comment: Cool! That worked!!! I wonder why base URL didn't work, but whatever... :)

Comment: For anyone who finds this answer, wildcards aren't allowed in Azure AD reply URLs anymore. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/tushargupta51/5fa6d000357120adbc8fd1d5c68853c4) helped me determine the best SPA solution.